# Cannot connect using wldap32 and apacheds over TLS (LDAPS)

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, ldap, apacheds

I am using a dynamic language that via FFI it wraps the wldap32 dll. I am using ApacheDS and I can perfectly connect to it from my client using normal LDAP. However, I cannot connect to it when using LDAPS. Yes, the checkbox is checked to start LDAP (on port 10636) and everything seems fine. In fact, from within ApacheDS I can open a connection to LDAPS and it works. The problem is from my client.

What I noticed is that in the logs, the following is printed:

```
[17:28:23] WARN [org.apache.directory.server.ldap.LdapProtocolHandler] - Unexpected exception forcing session to close: sending disconnect notice to client.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Improper close state: Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 7 sequenceNumber = 1
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.closeOutbound(SslHandler.java:497)
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.initiateClosure(SslFilter.java:762)
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.filterClose(SslFilter.java:693)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callPreviousFilterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:776)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1600(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.filterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1155)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.filterClose(IoFilterAdapter.java:146)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callPreviousFilterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:776)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1600(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.filterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1155)
at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter.filterClose(ExecutorFilter.java:608)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callPreviousFilterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:776)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1600(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.filterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1155)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.filterClose(IoFilterAdapter.java:146)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callPreviousFilterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:776)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireFilterClose(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:769)
at org.apache.mina.core.session.AbstractIoSession.closeNow(AbstractIoSession.java:353)
at org.apache.mina.core.service.IoHandlerAdapter.inputClosed(IoHandlerAdapter.java:102)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:997)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:735)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1119)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.inputClosed(IoFilterAdapter.java:154)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:735)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1119)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.inputClosed(IoFilterAdapter.java:154)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:735)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1119)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.inputClosed(IoFilterAdapter.java:154)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:735)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1119)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.inputClosed(IoFilterAdapter.java:154)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:735)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:728)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:556)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$1200(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:68)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1222)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1211)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:683)
at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

On my C client, I get the error "LDAP_SERVER_DOWN (81)" when calling the function ldap_simple_bind_s()

Does this tell anything to anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the issue and the solution.

In my dynamic language I was getting the "LDAP_SERVER_DOWN (81)". The next step I did is to run a C program that did pretty much the same I was doing from my dynamic language. For that, I compiled and executed [this example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ldap/example-code-for-establishing-a-session-over-ssl?redirectedfrom=MSDN). With this C program, it was also failing and with the same error: "ldap_connect failed with 0x51.".

Finally, I checked in Windows' Event Viewer, and I found the following error:

```
"The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an untrusted certificate authority. Because of this, none of the data contained in the certificate can be validated. The TLS connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate.
 The SSPI client process is ldaptest (PID: 4688)."
```

So that made me realize the problem was the self signed untrusted certificate being used by ApacheDS LDAPS server.

Following [this guide](https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/3.3-enabling-ssl.html), I created a custom certificate. Of course, even if I followed all those steps and I plugged the generated cert into ApacheDS, I would still have the same issue. However, I realized that there is a way you can tell Windows to "trust" your self signed certificate. I followed [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/sdn/articles/installing-the-trusted-root-certificate). More precisely, I took the generated certificate of the previous step, and I did the steps 5 to 7, which means basically to install the certificate in what Windows calls the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities store".

After that, I could successfully connect :)